# Where is the bifunctor for functions in haskell?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

I can't find bifunctor analog of fmap.

Explanation:

Functor for objects - datatype constructor. Type -
`a -> f a`

Functor for functions - `fmap`. Type - `(a -> b) -> (fa -> fb)`

Bifunctor for objects - result of `bimap f g`, where `f :: (a -> a')`, `g :: (b -> b')`. Type - `p a b -> p a' b'`

Bifunctor for functions - ?. Type - `p (a -> b) (c -> d) -> p (a' -> b') (c' -> d')`

Here is why I think bifunctor have such type (am I right?) with some example

[image]

---

UPDATE

[image]

---

UPDATE2

`p (a -> b) (c -> d) -> p (a' -> b') (c' -> d')` in the image above is morphism from bifunctor to bifunctor and also profunctor (because all functions are profunctors)

Summary:

I've thought `p (a -> b) (c -> d) -> p (a' -> b') (c' -> d')` is bifunctor for functions, but it's not. Bifunctor for morphisms is `bimap. Type: (a -> b) -> (α -> β) -> p a α -> p b β.`

I've thought `p (a -> b) (c -> d) -> p (a' -> b') (c' -> d')` is something unusual, but it's not, it's just function

Comment: A function is a *profunctor*, it is contravariant in the argument (`contramap`), and covariant in the return type (`fmap`). It is called `dimap`: `dimap :: (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> p b c -> p a d`. For the arrow type: `(a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> (b -> c) -> a -> d` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.3/docs/Data-Profunctor.html#t:Profunctor)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov following my example, how to get function with type `(Int, Float) -> (Id Int, Id2 Float)` using `dimap` ?

Comment: I think the title could be slightly misleading, if I'm understanding you correctly. I think you are saying: there are two "parts" to any functor, a type-level part (you're calling it "functor for objects," but I would definitely suggest saying type-level) and the value-level part (which is `fmap`) and that you are asking what the value-level part of a bifunctor is. Is that what you're asking? (Incidentally, if it is, the "functor for objects" part is not correct. It is at a type-level and you are talking about data constructors, which are value-level if I am interpreting correctly).

Comment: Reading through it again, I'm a bit less confident that I'm correct in how I read the question before. Maybe you could reword it slightly? What specifically do you mean by all of the things you are mentioning (like what are `Id` and `Id2` and what relation does the type signature `p (a -> b) (c -> d) -> p (a' -> b') (c' -> d')` have to the rest of what you're asking about)?

Comment: @DavidYoung re `what relation` - it's on image

Comment: as the start of your post,  I'd expect the second sentence to follow the first, as "Bifunctor for objects - datatype constructor. Type - `a -> b -> p a b`. Bifunctor for functions - `bimap`. Type - `(a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> (p a c -> p b d)`."

Comment: @WillNess maybe you right, the phrase `all products and coproducts are bifunctors` says that you are right. Then my graph is wrong

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Functor for objects - datatype constructor. Type - `a -> f a`
>
> Functor for functions - `fmap`. Type - `(a -> b) -> (fa -> fb)`

Although this makes broadly sense, it is important to realise that the arrows above have three different meanings.

> Functor for objects - datatype constructor. Type - `a ⟼ f a`
>
> Functor for functions - `fmap`. Type - `(a ⟿ b) ⟶ (f a ⟿ f b)`

where

- `⟼` is a type-level “maps-to symbol” that associates the type `a` with a type `f a`. This does *not* have anything to do with value-level functions whose domain is `a` and codomain `f a`. (Those are found in applicatives/monads, but that's a different story.)
- `⟿` is a type constructor for some morphism. In the **Hask** category, those morphisms happen to be Haskell functions, but that's just a special case.
- `⟶` is an actual function-type constructor.

You may for now forget about the distinction between the latter two, but `⟼` and `⟶` are really quite different conceptually<sup>†</sup>. Basically, `⟼` is like the arrow you write in a *lambda*

```
Maybe :: Type -> Type
Maybe = \a ⟼ Maybe a
```

whereas `⟶` is just a way to express that you're abstracting over function-things.

Another related thing that might not be clear is that the *objects* you're talking about are *Haskell types*. Not values (as OO objects are).

So, I would phrase the listing you gave above thus:

- Functor

  - for objects: datatype constructor. Kind `Type -> Type`, mapping-association `a ⟼ f a`.
  - for morphisms: `fmap`. Type: `(a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`.
- Bifunctor

  - for objects: datatype constructor. Kind `Type×Type -> Type`, or curried `Type -> Type -> Type`, mapping-association `a ⟼ b ⟼ p a b`.
  - for morphisms: `bimap`. Type: `(a -> b) -> (α -> β) -> p a α -> p b β`.

---

<sup>†</sup><sub>Actually, Haskell does not have `⟼` or what you wrote with `a -> f a`. This would be a type-level lambda, but type-level functions can actually only be expressed as *type families*, i.e. the closest you could get to expressing `a ⟼ f a` is `type instance Functored a = f a`.</sub>

Comment: @WillNess it's actually copied from the question. Not sure that was intentional;  it could make a bit of sense to treat `f a` as an “atomic” type at that point. But, not that much sense, I think I'll change this.

Comment: I have updated the image, but I still dont understand how `p (a -> b) (c -> d) -> p (a' -> b') (c' -> d')` is profunctor, especially when `p` is `(,)`. Following my example, how to get function with type `(Int, Float) -> (Id Int, Id2 Float)` using `dimap`

Comment: @srghma [functors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#t:Functor) have fmap ( `[x]-f-` ), [bifunctors](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#t:Bifunctor) have bimap ( `[x,y]-(f,g)-` ), [*profunctors*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/profunctors-5.3/docs/Data-Profunctor.html#t:Profunctor) have dimap ( `-f-[x-y]-g-` ).

Comment: @WillNess I'm sorry, the previous comment should have been written as: I have updated the image, but I still don't understand how morphism on my second image in question that have type `p (a -> b) (c -> d) -> p (a' -> b') (c' -> d')` is profunctor (as @YuvalItzchakov pointed out), especially when `p` is `(,)`. On the image in question I provided examples for some parts of graph. Following this examples, this morphism should have type `(Int, Float) -> (Id Int, Id2 Float)`, but I don't understand how to get this type using `dimap`

Comment: @srghma you do this using bimap as the answer by chepner is showing. the functions themselves can be treated as profunctors, or used to implement a bifunctor (e.g.) behaviour, like with bimap. (IOW you can ignore that comment, it is not relevant here, I think.)

Comment: @WillNess ok, he have said this about functions in general, not about this particular morphism. This morphism is constructed using bimap too. tnx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `Bifunctor` instance for `(->)`, just `(,)`:

```
b1 :: a -> Id a
b2 :: a -> Id2 a

-- instance Bifunctor (,) where
--   bimap f g (x, y) = (f x, g y)

f :: (Int, Float) -> (Id Int, Id2 Float)
f = bimap b1 b2
```